# Stream GroupingBy for an Object Inside another Different Object

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have three Objects as below :

```
public class A {
     private int a;
     private ...
     private B b;
    //getters setters for B
}

public class B {
     private String name;
     private ... 
     private C c;
    //getters setters for C
}

public class C {
     private Long id;
     private ... 
}
```

I'm having a `List<A>` with `B'`s Object in every `A` and `C`'s Object In every `B`.

I want to group A list by C.id in a map `Map<C,List<A>>`

How do I achieve this using `groupingBy` method of `Stream`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Map<Long, List<A>> resultSet = 
       myList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getB().getC().getId()));
```

**edit:**

Since you want a `Map<C, List<A>>` as the receiver type of the result set then you'll need to override `equals` and `hashcode` in your `C` class like this:

```
class C {
     public Long getId() {
         return id;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (this == o) return true;
         if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

         C c = (C) o;

         return id != null ? id.equals(c.id) : c.id == null;
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
     }

     private Long id;
}
```

Now, you can do:

```
Map<C,List<A>> resultSet = 
     myList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getB().getC()));
```

This means all `A` objects that have the same `C.id` will be in the same bucket (i.e group).

Comment: I made an edit , I actually need Object of C in map not Id, Its Map<C,List<A>> and not Map<Long,List<A>> but I want to group by C.id

Comment: @iamP _I want to group A list by C.id in a map Map<C,List<A>>_, well if you group by C.id then you cannot have `Map<C,List<A>>`. do you want to group by `C` then? you can override `equals` and `hashcode` in `C` then group by `C`.

Comment: I can group by C, but I am not sure if Objects with same C.id will be equal